# Buffer scope variable not exists when run autocmd BufUnload

Tags: vimscript, buffers, autocmd, quit, hidden-buffers

**Describe the issue**

I use a vim plugin that when use Vim to open a ipynb (python notebook) file, will call `system` function to use `jupytext` create corresponding python file to enable use like, YCM to help coding. This plugin set a autocmd BufUnload for the python file buffer to delete the python file when I quit Vim .

The bug is if the current buffer in current window is not the python file when quit Vim, the python file still there after quit Vim.

**To Reproduce**

I turn the plugin to a minimal version just vimscript.

1. Copy file `test_unload.vim` to ~/.vim/plugin (content of test_unload.vim will post below) .
2. `touch tt.ipynb && vim tt.ipynb`
3. `:e tt.c`
4. `:q`

After above steps, their should no `tt.py` file on disk, but have on `tt.py`.

**Contents of test_unload.vim**

```
if exists("loaded_test")
  finish
endif

function! s:read_from_ipynb()  "{{{
  if expand("<afile>:e") != "ipynb"
    echo "Not an ipynb file."
    return
  endif
  let l:filename = expand("%:p")
  let l:py_file = fnamemodify(l:filename, ":r") . ".py"
  " create python file
  call system('sleep 1;echo 123 > ' . l:py_file)
  " open the py file, wipe the ipynb file
  let l:bufnr = bufnr("%")
  execute "edit " . l:py_file
  execute "bwipeout" . l:bufnr
  set filetype=python
  execute "autocmd ipynb BufUnload <buffer> call s:cleanup()"
  let b:ipynb_file = l:filename
endfunction  "}}}

function! s:cleanup()  "{{{
  if !exists("b:ipynb_file")
    echo "Not a ipynb py file."
    return
  endif
  call delete(expand("<afile>:p"))
endfunction  "}}}

augroup ipynb
  au!
  autocmd BufReadPost *.ipynb call s:read_from_ipynb()
augroup END

let loaded_test = 1
```

What's in vimrc:

```
hmanx ~ » cat .vimrc            
set hidden
hmanx ~ »
```

**Expected behavior**

`tt.py` deleted by autocmd BufUnload when quit Vim.

**Environment:**

- Vim version: 8.2.1989-2
- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Terminal: Konsole

**Additional context**

I found the autocmd BufUnload did triggered when quit Vim, but it returned before delete `tt.py` as the condition `!exists("b:ipynb_file")` is true.

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [`:help BufUnload`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#BufUnload):

> **NOTE:** When this autocommand is executed, the current buffer `%` may be different from the buffer being unloaded `<afile>`.

So you should use [`getbufvar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getbufvar%28%29) to access the contents of that variable for the buffer being unloaded.

```
if getbufvar(+expand("<abuf>"), "ipynb_file") != ""
```

(Using `expand("<afile>")` instead of `+expand("<abuf>")` also works.)

This depends on the variable having contents that are different from an empty string, so it's not exactly equivalent to an `exists()` check. If you want to check for the variable existing exactly, then pass a sentinel value (such as `v:none`) as the third optional argument to `getbufvar()` and check for it.

```
if getbufvar(+expand("<abuf>"), "ipynb_file", v:none) != v:none
```

Comment: You probably want to replace `"<abuf>"` with `+expand('<abuf>')`.  You need `expand()` for Vim to expand the special characters `<abuf>` into a string containing a buffer number, and you need `+` to cast the string into a number; this matters because `getbufvar()` parses its first argument just like `bufname()`, and the latter handles a string like a pattern, which is here undesirable.

Comment: @user938271 Hmmm, that's odd, because I tested that (in the exact situation described above) and it seemed to work correctly for me.

Comment: After running [this shell command](https://0x0.st/ihIR.txt), the output of `:mess` is empty.  Which means that when `BufUnload` was fired by `:bd 2`, `:echom` was not run, and the `getbufvar()` condition unexpectedly failed.  OTOH, after running [this other shell command](https://0x0.st/ihIh.txt), the output of `:mess` contains `test`.  Which means that when `BufUnload` was fired by `:bd 2`, `:echom` *was* run, and the `getbufvar()` condition succeeded.  The only difference between the 2 commands is `+expand()`.

Comment: Thanks @user938271, I'll definitely take a closer look! I want to set this scenario up again, to see why it seemed to work for me first time I tested it... Your feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your discussions and @filbranden 's great answer!

Answer (score 1):

The current buffer and file is behind `<afile>`, not `%`